# Logic in Web.API to load data while scrolling

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm basic `web.api` developer. I've almost 10000 records of data. As it is a huge data, basically takes more time to load. So, front end Dev. *asked me to give an `API` such a way that he can pass the size of the records per scroll.*

So, my question is *Data Loading while scrolling* should done by front end developer or `web.api` developer?. If it is `web.api` side how can i do that?

Please help me!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it in both client's side and server side. You need to plan your table in the database that it will provide you options for paging so you can retrieve the data by a bulk of data. For example, `select * from youTable whrere id between 1 and 50`.

in angular, you have to use en event that will be fired every time when you scroll down and call to the web API service. You need to manage the data you already got and the data you will going to get and to send the indexes every time.
nice link in angular - https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically front-end developer send a request for data to API with pagination parameter, for example :
for the first time request is like 
http://example.com?page=1
here API should return for example first 1-20 data, for the second request the page number is incremented like http://example.com?page=2 so API return 21-40 data and so on.

It may possible front-end developer also pass the number of data required for each request, so you have to send the data in response as request.